# Scrape html tables and combine data into mongodb with scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping from 2 differnt tables and want to combine the data into MongoDB

Now I have a problem with the second table I want to scrape. 
The Table has 1 table header and 5 table rows
how can I scrape the table that the MongoDB field has all the elements(column) of the table

The table i want to scrape looks like this
https://codepen.io/linkslegend/pen/JjPrqLq

This is the code I have sofar

```
import scrapy
import pymongo
from ..items import testItem


class IssSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://de.iss.fst.com/dichtungen/radialwellendichtringe/rwdr-mit-geschlossenem-kafig/ba"]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("I just visted:" + response.url)
        urls = response.css('.details-button > a::attr(href)').extract()

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        # follow paignation link
        next_page_url = response.css('li.item  > a.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = testItem()
        item['Artikelnummer'] = response.css('td[data-th="Artikelnummer"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Hersteller'] = response.css('td[data-th="Hersteller"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Materialvariante'] = response.css('td[data-th="Materialvariante"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Material'] = response.css('td[data-th="Material"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Gewicht_Gramm'] = response.css('td[data-th="Gewicht (Gramm)"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Gehaeusedurchmesser'] = response.css('td[data-th="Gehäusedurchmesser"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Breite'] = response.css('td[data-th="Breite"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Innendurchmesser'] = response.css('td[data-th="Innendurchmesser"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Wellendurchmesser'] = response.css('td[data-th="Wellendurchmesser"]::text').extract_first().strip(),
        item['Außendurchmesser'] = response.css('td[data-th="Außendurchmesser"]::text').extract_first().strip(),

        for row in response.css('tr.offer'):
            item['Lieferant'] = row.css('td.vendor > span.offer-vendor::text').extract_first().strip(),
            item['Anforderungsmenge'] = row.css('td.item-no > span.offer-item-no::text').extract_first().strip(),
            item['Lieferzeit'] = row.css('td.replenishment-time > span.offer-replenishment-time::text').extract_first().strip(),
            item['PreisproStueck'] = row.css('td.cell.price-per-item > span.offer-price-per-item > span.price::text').extract_first().strip()

        yield item
```

and this is the pipeline for mongodb

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import pymongo

class testPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient(
            "localhost",
            27017
        )

        db = self.conn["test_db"]
        self.collection = db["test_tb"]


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

[my current MongoDB looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgKo5.png)

[This is how I want MongoDB to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NrNh.jpg)

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're overwriting the values for Lieferant, Anforderungsmenge, Lieferzeit & PreisproStueck in your loop.
You can try substituting it with the following:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
    item = testItem()
    ...
    lieferants = []
    anforderungsmenges = []
    lieferzeits = []
    preisprostuecks = []
    for row in response.css('tr.offer'):
        lieferant = row.css('td.vendor > span.offer-vendor::text').extract_first().strip(),
        anforderungsmenge = row.css('td.item-no > span.offer-item-no::text').extract_first().strip(),
        lieferzeit = row.css('td.replenishment-time > span.offer-replenishment-time::text').extract_first().strip(),
        preisprostueck = row.css('td.cell.price-per-item > span.offer-price-per-item > span.price::text').extract_first().strip()
        lieferants.append(lieferant)
        anforderungsmenges.append(anforderungsmenge)
        lieferzeits.append(lieferzeit)
        preisprostuecks.append(preisprostueck)
    item['lieferants'] = lieferants
    item['anforderungsmenges'] = anforderungsmenges
    item['lieferzeits'] = lieferzeits
    item['preisprostuecks'] = preisprostuecks
    yield item
```

You can also get the lists directly instead of looping over them, similar to the below (untested) code:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
    item = testItem()
    ...
    item['lieferants'] = [lieferant.strip() for lieferant in response.css('tr.offer > td.vendor > span.offer-vendor::text').extract()]
    item['anforderungsmenges'] = [anforderungsmenge.strip() for anforderungsmenge in response.css('td.replenishment-time > span.offer-replenishment-time::text').extract()]
    item['lieferzeits'] = [lieferzeit.strip() for lieferzeit in response.css('td.cell.price-per-item > span.offer-price-per-item > span.price::text').extract()]
    item['preisprostuecks'] = [preisprostueck.strip() for preisprostueck in response.css('td.cell.price-per-item > span.offer-price-per-item > span.price::text').extract()]
    yield item
```